# Can Copy and Paste from PDF have no "forced" hyphenation?

Tags: pdf, preview

I found that if using Acrobat 10 to copy and paste to my gmail, the text will be all messed up, but if I use Mac's Preview app to copy and paste to gmail, then the text is 99% good -- with the heading font size, color, etc, all in good proportion and formatting relative to other text.

However, there is one thing:  the forced hyphenation.  Suppose the PDF has

```
Mary has a little lamb.  Johnny has a little chicken.  Michael has a soft-
ware computer.
```

So if the above is copied and pasted else where, it may appear as:

```
Mary has a little lamb.  Johnny has a little
chicken.  Michael has a soft- ware computer.
```

So the "forced" hyphenation is added like that.  It doesn't look easy, but is there really a way to removed all these forced hyphenations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most text editors have a search and replace function.  Somwetimes you can directly to access it with `CTRL` +`H`.

You can use this to search all instances of "- " (hyphen and a space) and replace it with "" (nothing).  You would have to check that there are no other occurrences of a hyphen and space which you do not want to replace before doing this.

Comment: this is one good solution... if somebody told me this original problem I might have spotted the same answer, but if I see this problem myself I thought of something else... weird... i was looking more in the level of PDF and see if the hyphenation can be skipped...